# Parse data from one column to multiple columns, no fixed delimitation (MS Access, SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following field:

```
: joe

: doe

: 1231231234

: abcd.abcd@email.com

Field(s) of Interest: Trucking   

Certifications: CDL

: Birmingham

: Michigan

Are you willing to relocate?: No

If Yes, in which states?: 

Date Available (DD214): 07/17/2015

Drivers Only: Interest in training

Upload Resume:
```

I would like to parse this field and insert it in multiple fields like: first name, last name, phone number, email, field of interest, certifications, city, state, date available, and drivers only.

Is this possible?

Comment: garbage in, garbage out. given your field is basically a garbage dump of "random" data, good luck...

Comment: If you can figure out what logic to use for doing it, the rest is just programming.

Comment: There's a new row between each field, how could I read "enter" or "end of line"?

Comment: If you have the original file and it is a text file, it will probably have \n or \r\n at the end of each line. If this is in SQL already and all of the values have a `:` in them, you can use only the parts that come after using `SUSBTRING` and `CHARINDEX`

Comment: the field is in a mysql database which I've linked to MS Access, and now I'm trying to parse it in multiple fields.

Comment: I think the key is to detect the end of a row and `:`

Comment: Could I read backwards? from the end of row to `:`, and when i find `:` to jump to the next field?

Comment: Does the solution have to be SQL only, or can you use some programming language as well? Are the fields always in the same order, so you can for instance asume that the forth field is always the email?

Comment: Yes, the fields are in the same order and same format all the time. One problem could be that some fields are empty, and after `:` there's nothing afterwards. It has to be in SQL, because I have the table in MS Access, mySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this *is* possible (at least with MySQL):

```
create table `tempTable` (`tempContent` VARCHAR(255));
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/myFile.txt' INTO TABLE `tempTable` LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

delete from tempTable where `tempContent` = '';

CREATE TABLE myData (  
  first_name VARCHAR(255), 
  last_name VARCHAR(255), 
  phone_number VARCHAR(255), 
  email VARCHAR(255), 
  field_of_interest VARCHAR(255), 
  certifications VARCHAR(255), 
  city VARCHAR(255), 
  state VARCHAR(255), 
  relocate VARCHAR(255),
  relocate_states VARCHAR(255),
  date_available VARCHAR(255), 
  drivers_only VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO myData (first_name) select replace(`tempContent`, ': ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 0,1;
INSERT INTO myData (last_name) select  replace(`tempContent`, ': ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 1,1;
INSERT INTO myData (phone_number) select  replace(`tempContent`, ': ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 2,1;
INSERT INTO myData (email) select  replace(`tempContent`, ': ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 3,1;
INSERT INTO myData (field_of_interest) select replace(`tempContent`, 'Field(s) of Interest: ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 4,1;
INSERT INTO myData (certifications) select replace(`tempContent`, 'Certifications: ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 5,1;
INSERT INTO myData (city) select replace(`tempContent`, ': ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 6,1;
INSERT INTO myData (state) select replace(`tempContent`, ': ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 7,1;
INSERT INTO myData (relocate) select replace(`tempContent`, 'Are you willing to relocate?: ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 8,1;
INSERT INTO myData (relocate_states) select replace(`tempContent`, 'If Yes, in which states?: ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 9,1;
INSERT INTO myData (date_available) select replace(`tempContent`, 'Date Available (DD214): ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 10,1;
INSERT INTO myData (drivers_only) select replace(`tempContent`, 'Drivers Only: ', '') from `tempTable` LIMIT 11,1;

select * from myData;
```

Comment: This will work I think. I need a new table in mySQL right? Thanks for your elaborate answer!

Comment: one question @Benvorth: the original table(one column) is continuously updating from the internet (it's an online form). If I create the new table with your new method, is this new table also to update itself automatically when data is entered in the original table(one column)?

Comment: You will get one line of data in table `myData` for each file you Import. Make sure to delete table `tempTable` before you load a new file

Comment: there's no way of doing this for the whole original table, and then to automatically update? it has over 130 rows.  And every day it gets 5-10 new rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment**

Yes, it is possible.

We will be able to give you better insight if you tell us how the data is entering the system, for example in an Excel file.

Assuming you have a table with one column and these 13 rows. What you need to do now:

- Add 2 columns to the table
- Write a stored procedure to do a row by row operation to insert data in those two columns
- First column will be hard-coded to have first name, last name, phone number, email, field of interest, certifications, city, state, date available, and drivers only
- Second column will have a substring from ":" till the end of string

Points to remember

1. Make sure your second new column allows null and has a suitable datatype
2. More optimal way will be to pivot the data and store it in another table with columns like FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber... and so on

Mention the data source and I can help you in programming it.

Comment: The data entering the system through an online form, and it's stored like this in a mysql database. I could link the mySQL table into an excel spreadsheet if that would help.

Comment: How? in what format? like I am interpreting it to be or like @Benvorth has assumed it to be?
and no.. all can be done in database itself. I mentioned Excel just as an example :)

Comment: the data is in .sql format. I'm connecting MS Access through ODBC to the server. @Benvorth 's solution will work. I'll make a new table in the mysql database and then connect to that table through ODBC.